# After removing checkbox from checkboxlist, why checkbox isn't adding?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In this program I am dynamically adding CheckBox (by taking input from textbox) in CheckBoxList which itself is created dynamically.

Now when I add checkbox and remove it, everything works fine. When I again try to add checkbox, it is adding in the ArrayList as well as CheckboxList but not showing on the page.

Working on this from past 2 days but couldn't figure out. Please Help!!!

Thank You!

```
<!--chkboxlist.aspx-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
 <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtchkboxname" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>

   </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
//chkboxlist.aspx.cs

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class chkboxlist : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  static ArrayList arlst = new ArrayList();
  CheckBoxList chklst = new CheckBoxList();
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (txtchkboxname.Text != "")
    {
        arlst.Add(txtchkboxname.Text);
        txtchkboxname.Text = "";
    }
    chklst.DataSource = arlst;
    chklst.DataBind();
    chklst.AutoPostBack = true;
    chklst.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.chklst_OnSelectedIndexChanged);
    form1.Controls.Add(chklst);
  }

  protected void chklst_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    arlst.RemoveAt(chklst.SelectedIndex);
    chklst.DataSource = arlst;
    chklst.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add place holder and try to add checkboxlist within place holder instead of form. Also write textbox's text changed event to add items instead of in page load.

Comment: on page load write if(!IsPostback) inside it your code.

Comment: Hi Piyush Khatri,
I did what you said. I wrote text changed event to add items but in this case adding checkboxes works fine but when I select the Checkboxes, "chklst_OnSelectedIndexChanged" doesn't work.
I tried with the placeholder too but no effect.

Comment: Hi Manish Goswami, I wrote what you said but no change.